# How to convert List<string[]> to string[,]?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I converted a 2D array (`string[,]`) to the list below successfully. Now, how can I convert the List below back to a 2D array (`string[,]`)?

```
List<string[]> NameList = new List<string[]>();
```

This is how I converted the 2D array to list:

```
List<string[]> NameList = new List<string[]>();
string[,] Name2DArray = new string[Rows.Count, 3];

for (int i = 0; i < Name2DArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   string[] temp = new string[Name2DArray.GetLength(1)];
   for (int n = 0; n < temp.Length; n++)
   {
       temp[n] = Name2DArray[i, n];
   }

   NameList.Add(temp);
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems have you had in those attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: If the conversion from the array to the list worked successfully, why do you have a problem the other way round? It's not much different.

Comment: show us how did you convert it to `List<string[]>`

Comment: I added the code that converts 2D array to List string[] .

Comment: @user2142250 Great.  Now show us what you have tried to do so far to solve *this* problem, and explain what problems you are having with that attempted solution.

Comment: You will never get inside your initial `for` loop because you have not put anything in the `Name2DArray` at that point...  `GetLength(0) == 0`...

Comment: To Servy, I added the correct code. It was some stupid mistake I made in the nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions. I managed to fix the problem in my code. The conversion form List string[] to 2D array is now working. Below is the code:

```
string[,] newArray = new string[newTotalRows, 3];
for (int i = 0; i < NameList.Count; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < NameList[i].Length; j++)
    {        
        newArray[i, j] = NameList[i][j];
    }
}
```